# Why does Charlie want to kidnap the little girl?

Tags: plot-explanation, security

In the American movie *[Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_(film))*, Charlie kidnapped the little girl Jamie. She escaped from him and hid herself in a mall. Still, he was stalking her. Why does Charlie want to kidnap the little girl?

Answer (score 2):

In the movie, Charlie claims to be Jamie's father first. Later we can see that she is a trial witness and got attacked while transporting her, and that's how she gets to the mall.

Charlie and his gang of soldiers are there to get her and stop her from testifying against them.